# string substitution in C

Tags: c, string

I am working on a  C program and the program statement is as follows:

> Given a string S, and a list of strings of positive length,
>   F1,R1,F2,R2,...,FN,RN, proceed to find in order the occurrences
>   (left-to-right) of Fi in S and replace them with Ri. All strings are
>   over alphabet { 0, 1 }. Searching should consider only contiguous
>   pieces of S that have not been subject to replacements on prior
>   iterations. An iteration of the algorithm should not write over any
>   previous replacement by the algorithm.
>
> Input sample:
>
> Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename.
>   Each line in this file is one test case. Each test case will contain a
>   string, then a semicolon and then a list of comma separated
>   strings.eg.
>
> 10011011001;0110,1001,1001,0,10,11
>
> Output sample:
>
> For each line of input, print out the string after substitutions have
>   been made.eg.
>
> 11100110
>
> example: 10011011001 => 10100111001 [replacing 0110 with 1001] =>
>   10100110 [replacing 1001 with 0] => 11100110 [replacing 10 with 11] =>
>   11100110

My code is able to replace every corresponding Fn with Rn but it is over writing the previous replacements done. How to search only those contiguous pieces of S which have not been subjected to replacements.
I am doing the searching and substitution as follows:

```
  void string_sub(char s1[],char s2[],char s3[])
    {
            char r[200];
            printf("\n%s %s %s\n",s1,s2,s3);
            int i,j,k,x,y;
            char res[100];
            int len1=strlen(s1);
            int len2=strlen(s2);
            int len3=strlen(s3);
            j=0;
            i=0;
            while(i<len1)//searching for string 2 in string 1
            {
                    if(s2[j]==s1[i])
                    {
                            j++;
                            i++;
                            if(j==len2)
                            {
                              y=i;
                              x=i-len2;
                              break;        
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            if(s2[0]!=s1[i])
                            i++;
                            j=0;
                    }
            }
            k=0;
            for(i=0;i<x;i++)
            {
                    r[k]=s1[i];
                    k++;
            }
            for(i=0;i<len3;i++)
            {
                r[k]=s3[i];
                    k++;
            }
            i=y;
            while(i<len1)
            {
                    r[k]=s1[i];
                    k++;
                    i++;
            }
            r[k]='\0';//resultant string into r
            k=0;
           for(i=0;i<strlen(r);i++)//copying resultant string to s1
           {
            s1[k]=r[i];
            k++;
           }
           s1[k]='\0';
    }
```

My entire C Code is [here](http://ideone.com/upsKpO)

Comment: After the first substitution, your search space is *two* strings: 10 and 11001. Isn't that right? How are you keeping track of those?

Comment: That's my problem which i am facing!..How to keep the track of those two strings and search accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me, if I understand your code correctly, that you are calling your substitution code for each pair you get, and passing in the converted string each time. What I would do is pass a start offset into that function as well and then have that function return the location in the newly substituted string that you left off with the last substitution. The function would start searching s1 at your offset rather than at 0 each time. (Remember to not change your offset if you do not perform a substitution.) So in you main function, have an offset variable that starts at 0 and pass that in to the function, and also assign the result of the function to that variable so that next time you call it you will start at the last offset instead of the beginning. Does this make sense? If not I can try to break my answer down a bit better.

In your main function you would:

```
int offset = 0;
```

and then

```
offset = string_sub( offset, s1, s2, s3 );
```

your function will look something like this:

```
int string_sub( int offset, char* s1, char* s2, char* s3 )
{
...
```

and at the point where you have finished replacing the string you would:

```
offset = y;
```

and at the end you would do this

```
return( offset );
}
```

Does that help?

As @Mike noticed, my answer is not quite correct. I assumed incorrectly that you would ignore everything before the last point you looked at because I did not read the requirements thoroughly enough. Instead of passing in an offset and then returning a new offset, you need to pass in a structure that contains an array of ranges where each range is a range of characters that have been substituted and are as such, untouchable, and a count of how many ranges there are in that array. Since this is in C we don't have the luxury of easy array management so we will have to do this the hard way. I would make the structure look as follows:

```
#define MAX_RANGES (10)

struct RangeEntry
{
    int first;
    int last;
};

struct RangeData
{
    int numRanges;
    struct RangeEntry ranges[MAX_RANGES];
};
```

And then have your substitute function prototype look like this:

```
int string_sub( char* s1, char* s2, char* s3, struct RangeData* rangeData )
```

In your main function you would instantiate this structure, and initialize numRanges to 0, and then pass a pointer to this instance into your function. In your function you would have to look at s1 a little differently. Instead of just looking to see if you ran off the end of the string you would have to look to see if you run into any of those ranges. If you are matching then the match will have to end at the start of the next range. If you are not then you would have to continue looking after the end of the next range.

I hope this helps, and sorry for the wrong answer earlier.

Comment: Thanku!..Is it possible to explain a little more detail as to how to pass the offset!

Comment: "Where you left off" isn't necessarily the right place to start, though. Read the requirements again. After the first substitution, the search space consists of *two* strings: "10", which starts at position 0, and "11001" which starts at position 6.

Comment: Fair enough. I haven't had sleep yet, so a little groggy, but you are absolutely right @MikeSherrill'Catcall'. the idea is still the same but it now becomes a completely different answer. And what you pass back is not a single offset but a range of locations that have already been substituted. I will update my answer.